# Cropping content fails with lualatex, how come?

Tags: luatex, standalone, crop

I'm new to latex, I was wondering given this simple tex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}    
    \tikz \draw (0,0) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{document}
```

In the preview I can notice the page is getting cropped to the content as I wanted,
but when I try to:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi single_circle.tex
```

I get:

> ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros ! Undefined control sequence.
> \sa@placebox ->\newpage \global \pdfpagewidth
> =\wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageh... l.8 \end{document}
> ?  ! You can't use a prefix with `the character ='. <to be read again>  = l.8 \end{document} ?  ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again>  \global  l.8 \end{document} ?  ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). <to be read again>  \global  l.8 \end{document} ?  ! Undefined control sequence. \sa@placebox ...wd \sa@box \global \pdfpageheight  =\ht \sa@box \global \pape... l.8 \end{document} ?  ! You can't use a prefix with` the character ='. 
> = l.8 \end{document}
> ?  ! Missing number, treated as zero.   \global  l.8 \end{document}
> ?  ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).   \global  l.8 \end{document}
> ?
>
> Overfull \hbox (30.56pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 8--8
> []\TU/lmr/m/n/10 ==[]

How come it fails?
I just want to crop to the content and export it to svg by using:

```
lualatex --output-format=dvi single_circle.tex
dvisvgm  single_circle.dvi
```

Comment: works fine for me, is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: actually `\pdfpageheight` looks as if your system is too old. You probably need `\RequirePackage{luatex85} ` before the \documentclass.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Bingo!! it worked. 
Thank you, can you explain how did you it figure out? :)